# Need to listen on a port and then start a program

Tags: scripting

I am having a difficulty finding out to listen to a port when there is a connection on the port then start a program

so far i have

```
nc -l 3333 | vlc rtsp://192.168.0.1/media.amp
```

but that does not seem to wait for connection on the port.

any help appreciated

Erik

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the `-l`. So you wait for an incoming connection (like port knocking), and then start the program?

Comment: yes thats the idea, its actually a surevilance camera that will send the tcp message to the client and then vlc will start pulling the video stream from the camera. i am working on a project for the raspberry pi and building on top of this project, https://www.raspberrypi.org/magic-mirror/

Comment: This piped setup will start vlc immediately, and nc will send through anything it receives, that's why vlc dows not wait.

Comment: Check out this answer on how to exit a pipe: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45943/114502 Then maybe you can `&&` the vlc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the answer to my question

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 2 -lt 3 ]; do
        while ! nc -l localhost 80; do 
                                sleep 0.1;
                    done;
        echo "Rock'n'roll!" #execute the command here
done;
```